# Iterating over AJAX response

Tags: javascript, json, jquery

I'm trying to learn some front end engineering, but am getting caught up on what should be an easy thing to do.  I've checked other questions, and tried the nested `$each` recommended

I have a simple REST API that I wrote that returns this JSON when the page loads:

```
{"book":    
[{"authorFirstName":"Clive","authorLastName":"Cussler","genre":"Fiction","title":"Inca    
Gold"},{"authorFirstName":"Og","authorLastName":"Mandino","genre":"Self
Improvement","title":"The Greatest Salesman in the World"}, 
{"authorFirstName":"Bill","authorLastName":"O'Reilly","genre":"History","title":"Killing 
Lincoln"}]}
```

The problem is not getting this from the server; I get this when the page loads or when I go to the REST URL.  I'm having trouble rendering the page though.  Here's my AJAX call and success function:

```
function getAllBooks() {
    console.log("Getting all books");
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: rootURL, 
            dataType: "json",
            success: renderBookList
        });
}

function renderBookList(data) {
    $('#bookList li').remove();
    $.each(data, function(index, book) {
        $('#bookList').append('<li><a href="#">' + book.title + '</a></li>');
    });
}
```

If I change the line inside the `$each` function to be `book[0].title`, then I get the title for  the first book in the JSON.

What am I missing?  Is the issue with the JSON, that it's an object with one property (but the property is an array of objects)?

The server is JAX-RS and returns an `ArrayList<Book>` if that's germane. Thanks for any help.

Comment: `$.each(list, function)` should be `$.each(data.book, function)`, shouldn't it?

Comment: The `list` variable you're iterating over is never defined. Should that be `data` instead? If that's the case, try `$.each(data.book, function(index, book) {`

Comment: and even in data shouldn't you be accessing it as data.data[0].book?

Comment: Sorry, I have that in there from something else I tried (checking type of data and changing it to array).  I've changed my code in the question to reflect it, but it still isn't working right. Thanks for catching that.

Comment: @theshadowmonkey There's no `data` key in the JSON object.

Comment: From that JSON, `data.book` is the array to iterate over.

Comment: Also, a generic solution to this kind of problem: get comfortable with the `console.log` command. If you `console.log(book)` inside of that `$.each` loop you'll usually be able to solve this kind of problem pretty quickly.

Comment: @MichaelMior doesn't that success callback data object have other attributes than the JSON object being returned when returned from a REST API?

Comment: @theshadowmonkey The raw parsed JSON is passed directly to the callback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your book array is referenced by the `book` property in your JSON response.

```
function renderBookList(data) {
    $('#bookList li').remove();
    $.each(data.book, function(index, book) {
        $('#bookList').append('<li><a href="#">'+ book.title +'</a></li>');
    });
}
```

*NOTE: You should be caching `$('#bookList')` in a variable instead of retrieving it for each iterations.*